# Change mac's terminal theme using python

Tags: python, macos, command-line, terminal

How exactly can I change the theme of a mac terminal using python. I have a command line program and I want to have a specific theme for the terminal (other than the basic theme) as my command-line program starts.

Comment: Other than opening Terminal Preferences and altering the settings?

Comment: yes I want to know if there is a way to put the setting programed in the file i.e. as the program starts the file takes the programmed theme regardless of default setting. @khelwood

Comment: When you say "theme" do you actually mean `profile`? Terminal.app has no such thing as "themes".

Comment: Yes exactly! I meant to say profile. sorry for wrong use of word. @khelwood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Python `subprocess` module to call an `AppleScript`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

def asrun(ascript):

    osasc = subprocess.Popen(['osascript', '-'],
    stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return osasc.communicate(ascript)[0]

def asquote(astr):

    ascrpt = astr.replace('"', '" & quote & "')
    return '"{}"'.format(ascrpt)

ascript = '''
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set current settings of tabs of windows to settings set "Pro"
end tell
'''

asrun(ascript)
```

This will change all of the windows and tabs you currently have open. If you want it do change just one and not the others, or change the window when you launch terminal that's fairly easy to do. It's just a matter of determining which window or tab you want to change and how you are calling the script in the first place. This should give you an idea though of the basic means of how it works — so I've left this example fairly minimal so you can understand the basics of it.

To change the profile, substitute "Pro" with any profile name (even custom versions you've created) that are listed in Terminal.app.

Comment: Thanks so much bro! It really did help! Much appreciation:) (can't  upvote untill i get a reputaion of 15 tho, sorry) @I'L'l

Comment: @SimonTsehaye: You're welcome! You can mark the answer as correct though by clicking the `✓` underneath the score, which will also give you more reputation :)